# Isolation mode (registration free) COM setting in VC++ 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, regfreecom

How do I create a reference to an isolation mode (registration free) COM DLL in a VC++ 2008 project?

In a C# project it is as easy as toggling an `Isolated` property on a reference. How do I do the equivalent in a VC++ project?

Answer (score 0):

Project Properties > Configuration Properties > Manifest Tool > Isolated COM